# Functions with "Unstable" Antiderivatives in Terms of Elementary Functions

Tags: calculus, integration, examples-counterexamples, recreational-mathematics

I recently came across the following claim on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm):

[image: Image 1]

I assumed that this is due to a small change in one of the coefficients of the polynomial yielding a large change in the roots, but that cannot be the case here, as only the constant term changes. The number of real roots (two) also does not change. Is there a way to understand why this occurs? Is it something about the residues?

For a more open-ended follow-up question, are there other examples of this, that is, other functions with elementary antiderivatives that become non-elementary after some "small" change?

Comment: If you look at the exact real roots of $x^4+10x^2-96x-71$ and $x^4+10x^2-96x-72$ (quartics, so exact roots can be expressed in radicals) you get $\sqrt {3} \pm  \sqrt{ \sqrt{192} - 8}$ for the former and something incredibly messy for the latter.  So it is plausible that finding an integral or antiderivative for $f(x)$ might turn out to be simpler for the former case than the latter, since nice integrals are inherently fragile.  It is also plausible to believe such examples can be constructed and this is one such example

Comment: @Henry It sounds like it might be a number theoretic property of the coefficients, then.

Comment: @KleinFour That is my guess.  I have not checked, but I suspect that taking the derivative of $F(x)$ leads to some nice cancellations which are a result of the particular coefficients

Comment: That "constant term" is not a constant term: it's under a radical sign in the denominator, with lots of other stuff in their under the radical.